# read from stdin, and write to stdout, why my read() function alwasy return 1?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have a simple code to test read() and write() system call, as below

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    #define BUFFSIZE 4096
    int n;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];

    while (n=read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE) > 0) {

        if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n) {
            printf("write err.\n");
        }
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        printf("read error.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I run it like this:

```
$ ./a.out 
hello
h
```

I use gdb and find read() always returns 1.

Comment: Operator precedence: `>` wins over `=`. Avoid using assignment inside control expressions.

Comment: In other words: `n` always is `1` because `read() > 0` is `true`.

Comment: +1 @Lundin , but sometimes using assignment inside control expressions is handy. One just needs to use parantheses to secure order of operations.

Comment: @nomoresigsegv No, that's rarely ever true, most assignments inside such expressions originate from poor design. The main problem isn't even operator precedence or even the old = vs == mix-up, but the fact that you toss in side effects with other things in the same expression. In this case for example the loop could have been written as `int n=1; while (n > 0) { n = read ... }` or alternatively as `do while`.

Comment: @nomoresigsegv Cramming assignments into a conditional is **extremely** bug-prone.  It literally makes it harder for a human brain to understand because human brains can only track a small number of states/objects at any one time - 3-5 is the normal limit.  Even in the simple case, there's 1) function call 2) assignment 3) comparison 4) loop control.  You're immediately at the limit of what your brain can comprehend.  Why would anyone want to write bug-prone code that's harder to understand?  It's idiomatic?  It was also idiomatic to put lead in gasoline back in 1970.  Do better.

Comment: Yup - just don't do it.  'clever code' like that is a bug factory:(

Answer (score 3):

The statement:

```
while (n=read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE) > 0)
```

is parsed as:

```
while ( n = (read (STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZE) > 0))
```

The comparison operator `>` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`. Comparison and logical operators return the value `false` or `true`, which in this statement gets stored in the variable `n`. You need parentheses around the assignment to `n` in order to secure order of operations like so:

```
while ( (n = read (STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
```

Alternatively, the loop can be rewritten in this manner:

```
for (;;) {
    n = read (STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZE);
    if (n <= 0) {
        break;
    }

    if (write (STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n) {
        fputs ("write error.\n", stderr);
    }
}
```

Note that `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`.

Comment: No `else` needed:  `ssize_t n = read(...); if ( n <= 0 ) break;`

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, that's better. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You must put parentheses in the while condition, otherwise `n` is the result of `read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0`.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    #define BUFFSIZE 4096
    int n;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];

    while ((n=read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0) {

        if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n) {
            printf("write err.\n");
        }
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        printf("read error.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And now in case you happen to use one of the (poorly designed) mainstream compilers, you will no longer get warnings for slipping on the keyboard and writing `(n==read(...))` by accident. Because the parenthesis blocks that warning from happening (which is really stupid but that's how several compilers were designed). The proper solution is to remove the assignment from the control expression entirely.

Comment: @Lundin: in this particular case, both `while ((n == read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)` and `while (n == read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE) > 0)` would produce a warning because `n` is uninitialized at the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

**Higher level problem**

Save time.  Enable all warnings.  More efficient than posting on SO.

```
while (n=read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE) > 0) {

warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
```

and others.